# Learning iPhone programming coming from C# background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to put my foot in world of iPhone programming.  I got fair bit of experience with C# coding.

Should I go and start learning objective-C even before touching cocoa [or] there is better approach (i know nothing about iphone programming).

Are there any recommended books / blogs I should go through for my learning curve.

** If this is a duplicate question can someone point me the orginal question please **

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good book about Objective-C 2.0 for an experienced C/C++/Java/C# developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210919/a-good-book-about-objective-c-2-0-for-an-experienced-c-c-java-c-developer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [iPhone Application Development](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225) video lectures on iTunes -- it's a great way to get started.

Comment: Can't believe I left these tutorials off!  Excellent resource.

Comment: +1 this is how I learned. Any experienced programmer should be able to go through these pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

[Beginning Objective-C](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/scottcreynolds/archive/2009/02/05/beginning-objective-c-for-the-c-guy.aspx) for the C# guy by Scott Reynolds got me started on my path to developing my first IPhone app last month.

If you're a skilled C# dev, you'll find little friction in moving to Obj-C (aside from learning new APIs but that's to be expected in transitioning to any new environment.)

The main hurdle will be memory management, since there's no GC to handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple dev forums are great for learning how to develop for the iPhone.  But additionally you really need to become familiar with the Cocoa framework.  The widely accepted authority is this book by [Aaron Hillegass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Hillegass) called [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201726831).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend being familiar with straight C first. Objective-C is a strict superset of C, and you'll be working with things like pointers. You'll also understand where the C layer ends and the Objective-C layer begins, such as knowing why an NSInteger can't be inserted into an NSArray.